# My stroke settings on Illustrator are not working!

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

My stroke settings on Illustrator are not working like they typically do even though I have the units set for inches. So for instance, instead of having 0.25 be the thinnest available stroke it is 0.0078. This is throwing me off because when I choose 1 in it turns out to be a giant blob on the page. How can I fix this?

Comment: set the units on stroke to points. your strokes are set to 1 inch wide, which is pretty big unless you're doing a billboard.

Comment: Contact Adobe for technical support.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right measurements (pixels/points/inches)
Also  check if the strokes grow proportionally when enlarging/shrinking an object:

> General prefs. Check Scale Strokes & Effects.